# jQuery Function to bring in "offcanvas" slide-in menu is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar

I have tried and searched the internet dry without any solution to my problem. I have created an  list in which I modified to be located off the main screen as a slide-in menu using transform: translate (-100%). When the main navbar collapses into the mobile button, I intend to assign a jQuery function to the button in order to slide-in the offcanvas menu. However, the button does not respond no matter what and I need some aid. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
    /..The main navbar../
    <nav class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li class="products1"><a href="#2">Products</a></li>
            <li class="store1"><a href="#3">Store</a></li>
            <li class="about1"><a href="#4">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="discover1"><a href="#5">Discover</a></li>
            <li class="support1"><a href="#6">Support</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                /..The button that dosen't work../
                <button class="navbar-toggle pro-toggle pull-left">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                /..The menu that I want to slide in but dosen't work../
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="products"><a href="#2">Products</a></li>
                        <li class="store"><a href="#3">Store</a></li>
                        <li class="about"><a href="#4">About Us</a></li>
                        <li class="discover"><a href="#5">Discover</a></li>
                        <li class="support"><a href="#6">Support</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

/..The main CSS for the slide-in menu../

<style>
.main-navigation {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: white;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.main-navigation.open {
    transform: translateX(0);
}
</style>

/..The jQuery function that is supposed to slide-in the menu../

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.pro-toggle').on('click', function(){
            ${'.main-navigation').toggleClass('open');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

from `${'.main-navigation')` to `$('.main-navigation')`.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: jquery/js functions are wrapped in brackets `$(selector);` you have opened yours with a curly bracket `${selector)`

Comment: OH MY GOODNESS! Sorry for the caps but I just feel so stupid! I've literally been staring at my computer for 6 hours non-stop trying to figure out what was wrong. Hats off to you sir! Thanks!

Comment: you don't have to some times this type mistakes happend